# How to use createQuery with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Normally I use annotiations:`@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c")` with `JpaRepository`or predefined methods like `findAll`

but in my case I want to generate dynamic query.

```
String baseQuery =SELECT c FROM Country c`

if(age!=null)
  baseQuery+="WHERE c.age=20"
```

I need to perform same query from code level like this:

> Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");

but I dont use `EntityManager` in spring boot

How can I generate query from code level?

Comment: Sorry, but what prevents you from calling the findAll() method of your repository? Are you asking how to execute a JPA query when not using Spring Data JPA? If so, what have you tried, and what's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: I cant use findAll()  because I want generate dynamic query. 
query must depends on the input values

Comment: And what problem are you facing? Have you read the spring-data-jpa documentation to understand how to create custom repository methods? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour

Comment: I did not know how to get access to EntityManager, but I think anwser is create new class MyRepositoryImpl and define there EntityManager entityManage. Am I right?

Comment: The entity manager can be injected using `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create dynamic queries from code you can take advantage of Spring's `JdbcTemplate`. Using spring boot it is as simple as injecting [JdbcOperations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html) bean to your repository class (assuming you have provided spring-boot-starter-jdbc module to your project).

But remember! This solution uses SQL, not JPQL. That's why you have to use proper tables and columns names in queries and properly map result to objects (i.e. using [RowMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html))

This simple example worked fine for me (with different entity, but in same manner - I've adapted it to your example):

```
@Repository
public class CountryRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    private static String BASIC_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY";

    public List<Country> selectCoutry(Long age){
        String query = BASIC_QUERY;
        if (age != null){
            query += " WHERE AGE = ";
            query += age.toString();
        }

        //let's pretend that Country has constructor Conutry(String name, int age)
        return jdbcOperations.query(query, (rs, rowNum) -> 
            { return new Country(rs.getString("NAME"), rs.getInt("AGE");}
        );
    };

}
```

Then in service or whatever you inject CountryRepository and call method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Spring Boot, you can use Spring Data to create queries in your repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {

}
```

Not a 100% on syntax, but should be something similar.
Now you can **autowire** this class:

```
@Autowired
public CountryRepository countryRepo;
```

And all basic methods are already available to you like:

```
countryRepo.findOne(id);
countryRepo.find();
```

If you want to make more advanced queries, you can use Spring Data e.g.:

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {

    public Country findByNameAndContinent(String name, String continent);
}
```

This is just an example (a stupid one) of course and assumes your `Country` class has the field names 'name' and 'continent' and both are strings. More is available here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/
Section 5.3 more specifically.

PS: Make sure your `Country` class has the `@Entity` annotation

Comment: I'm sorry but I badly formulated the question, question was how to create custom query. Now I know I can do it by Implementation of custom repository functionality: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour